# Identify the largest value from a bunch of random numbers

Tags: javascript

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhaem/po12voLL/1/

I wrote a script that lets me specific the number of random numbers I want to display, and the max value any of those numbers can be. Like so:

```
var randomLimit = 100000
var numberCount = 20
var counter = 0;

document.write("<h1>" + numberCount + " random numbers. Max value of " + randomLimit + "</h1>" );

function randomNumber(limit) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * limit ) + 1;
  }

while ( counter < numberCount ) {
  document.write(randomNumber(randomLimit) + "<br>");
  counter++;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can evaluate all these numbers and identify the largest one (and make that line item bold).

I tried to do it by checking if the current "randomNum" is greater than the others, but doesn't work and doesn't seem like quite the right approach anyway as it seems like it needs to wait for all the numbers to be generated before picking the biggest? Would love any ideas.

```
while ( counter < numberCount ) {
  var randomNum = randomNumber(randomLimit)
  if (this.randomNum > randomNum) {
    document.write("<strong>" + randomNum + "</strong>" + " ");
  } else {
    document.write(randomNum + " ");
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `this.randomNum` and the `randomNum` you just declared? Have you checked that they're not actually the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all numbers in a array, find the max, then write them all as in this code.

It is not not the best solution, because it need 3 iterations over the array (one for generate, one for find the max, and the last one print the numbers) but I think it is clear, and I always err to readability over performance.

You can not resolve this problem with less than 2 iterations, because you can never know if the next value (being random) will be larger than the previous.

```js
var randomLimit = 100000
var numberCount = 20
var counter = 0;

document.write("<h1>" + numberCount + " random numbers. Max value of " + randomLimit + "</h1>" );

function randomNumber(limit) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * limit ) + 1;
}

// Generate random numbers
var randomNumbers = []
for( counter = 0; counter < numberCount; counter++ )
  randomNumbers.push(randomNumber(randomLimit))

// Find max value
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(this, randomNumbers)

// Write values
randomNumbers.forEach(function(value) {
  str = value;
  if(value == maxValue) str = "<strong>" + value + "</strong>";
  document.write(str + "<br />");
})
```

Comment: I hear you that maybe this isn't the most efficient, but its definitely the easiest to follow. So, this is how I'm gonna do it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

You can have a variable that keeps track of the largest number and update it if the current number is greater than the largest number. When you're done generating all the random numbers, find that number and bold it.

```js
var randomLimit = 100000
var numberCount = 20
var counter = 0;
var largestNumber = -1;

document.write("<h1>" + numberCount + " random numbers. Max value of " + randomLimit + "</h1>" );

function randomNumber(limit) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * limit ) + 1;
  }

while ( counter < numberCount ) {
  var currNumber = randomNumber(randomLimit);
  document.write("<span>" + currNumber + "</span><br>");
  if (currNumber > largestNumber)
    largestNumber = currNumber;
  counter++;
}

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].innerHTML == largestNumber) {
    list[i].innerHTML = "<strong>" + largestNumber + "</strong>";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="layer1">

 </div>
 <script src="randomNum.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, and how lazy you feel you could generate the big number from a higher set and randomly insert it. Not random.

Otherwise the Mozilla Developer Network says use [Math.max.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) or the 'spread operator'. Spread operator as per example.

```
var randomNums = []

while ( counter < numberCount ) {
  randomNums.push(randomNumber(randomLimit));
  counter++;
}

var maxIs = Math.max(...randomNums), i;

for (i=0; i<numberCount; ++i) { 
  var num = randomNums[i];
  if (num == maxIs) {
     document.write('<b>' + num  + '</b><br/>');
  } else {
    document.write(num + '<br/>')
  }
}
```